# How do I enable Gmail people widget?

Tags: gmail

I had thought this should be enabled for everyone at this point... but I still don't see it in any of my accounts (one regular and two Apps)

I have disabled all the extensions that could have messed with Gmail, and a few Labs, just in case.

Even my non-techie wife, using a non-english configuration has it. Any ideas on getting it to work?

Comment: It's a phased roll-out; you'll just have to be patient. My Google Apps account (for work) got it within days of launch. My personal Gmail account only got it a couple of days ago.

Comment: @AlEverett: that's a shame. Latest update from the official Gmail blog on June 10th said rollout should be complete "in the next couple weeks". It's been a month.

Comment: Apparently, I just have to keep waiting.

Answer (score 1):

`mail settings -> General -> people widget`

Is where the setting for the people widget. Make sure `Show the people widget` is checked

Comment: I don't have it :-(

Comment: @Diego Like @AL Everett says in his comment its a phased roll out (i didn't mention this before as I figured they'd of finished by now)